# How to run 2 Specrun Profile profile tests with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, specflow, specrun

i have Automation scripts for responsive design for Iphone 5 and Iphone 6. Is there any way we can run the same code under both the profile together?

Currently the way i have configured jenkins is run 2 separate  widnows batch command one by one like

```
 %WORKSPACE%\****.Tests\runtests.cmd FFResponsiveIphone5 "@responsive_test_Futures" Iphone5.html

 %WORKSPACE%\****.Tests\runtests.cmd FFResponsiveIphone6 "@responsive_test_Futures" Iphone6.html
```

Above is generating 2 seperate report but i was thinking to put both the profile run in one report .. Is there any way to do that and combine above both the statement .

Comment: What are the differences in your profiles files?
Perhaps it could be solved via Targets and ConfigurationFileTransformation?

Comment: @AndreasWillich Only difference between those profiles are height and width value for different device views. well i dont know how can we solve via targets or with profile transformation ?

    Also profile "FFResponsiveIphone5" and "FFResponsiveIphone6" are seperate profiles which i use to do transformations while executions and only difference is below Keys.

    1) Width
    2) Height
    3) Device